# Why hyperlinks in textboxes disappear when I save excel as PDF using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba which saves the excel sheet as PDF

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
```

the excel sheet has several textboxes, the hyperlinks to the web pages are linked to these boxes. When I save the excel via vba, the links disappear (only on MacOs, on Windows everything works just fine), when I save it manually they work.
What can be the reason for that? And how to solve it?